# Why is my delete viewonly deleting the latest entry?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to get my delete_entry view to delete the correct entry, however whichever delete button I click, it's referring to the same item_id. I have changed the view so that it prints the entry to be deleted rather than deleting it, and whichever button I choose from the list, it selects the same entry.

Is there something in my view that isn't working? My edit functionality is working as expected, so is it worth just changing delete_entry to work in the same way as EditHealth?

Health_hub_history.html:

```
                {% for item in stats %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.user }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.weight }} </td>
                    <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.run_distance }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.run_time }}</td>
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <td>
                        <a href="edit/{{ item.id }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Edit
                        </button>
                    </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"
                        tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Are you sure you want to delete
                                        this entry?</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                        aria-label="Close"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    If you just need to amend something, try the edit button.
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                        data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <a href="delete/{{ item.id }}"><button class="btn btn-danger">I'm
                                            sure</button></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Views.py:

```
def health_history(request):
    serialized_stats = []
    for stats in HealthStats.objects.filter(user=request.user):
        serialized_stats.append({
            "user": stats.user,
            "weight": stats.weight,
            "date": stats.date,
            "run_distance": stats.run_distance,
            "run_time": stats.run_time,
            "id": stats.id,
        })
    context = {
        "stats": serialized_stats
        }
    return render(request, 'health_hub_history.html', context)

def delete_entry(request, item_id):
    entry = get_object_or_404(HealthStats, id=item_id)
    print(entry)
    # entry.delete()
    return redirect("HealthHub:health_hub_history")

class EditHealth(UpdateView):
    model = HealthStats
    template_name = 'health_hub_edit.html'
    fields = ['weight', 'run_distance', 'run_time']
```

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('MyHealth/', views.health_hub, name='health_hub'),
    path('MyHealth/update', views.UpdateHealth.as_view(), name='health_hub_update'),
    path('MyHealth/history', views.health_history, name='health_hub_history'),
    path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url("favicon.ico"))),
    path('MyHealth/delete/<item_id>', views.delete_entry, name='health_hub_delete'),
    path('MyHealth/edit/<int:pk>', views.EditHealth.as_view(), name='health_hub_edit'),
]
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class HealthStats(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    run_distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    run_time = models.DurationField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'health_stats'
        ordering = ['-date']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('HealthHub:health_hub_history')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} | {self.date}"
```

Comment: Are you using DRF too?

Comment: Nope not for this

Comment: At last, share `HealthStats` model if possible, I think the problem is with javascript's default behaviour since whenever you click on any button the event is fired on latest element in DOM, so as a result it sends that id to delete view I think, not sure.

Comment: No problem, have added to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with id for staticBackdrop in DOM, there shouldn't be identical id's. You just need to add something to the id:

```
<td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                        data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop_{{item.id}}">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop_{{item.id}}" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"
                    tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Are you sure you want to delete
                                    this entry?</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                    aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                If you just need to amend something, try the edit button.
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                    data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                <a href="delete/{{ item.id }}"><button class="btn btn-danger">I'm
                                        sure</button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I added item.id to modal id. This will prevent multiply same ids in DOM.

Comment: That's not it- it just stopped the modal working :(